# Singleton array 1 cannot be considered a valid collection

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to present the confusion matrix after deep learning model, but there is an error, how can I fix it?

```
Y_pred = model.predict(X_val)
Y_pred_classes = np.argmax(Y_pred,axis = 1) 
Y_true = np.argmax(y_val,axis = 0) 
confusion_mtx = confusion_matrix(Y_true, Y_pred_classes) 
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
sns.heatmap(confusion_mtx, annot=True, linewidths=0.01,cmap="Greens",linecolor="gray", fmt= '.1f',ax=ax)
plt.xlabel("Predicted Label")
plt.ylabel("True Label")
plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
plt.show()
```

```
TypeError: Singleton array 1 cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

This is the output of `Y_true` and `Y_pred_classes`

```
Y_true
```

```
1
```

```
Y_pred_classes
```

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this code `#Y_true = np.argmax(y_val,axis = 0)` as `Y_true` already carries actual label values, you need not to find the max probable number. You can directly use `Y_true` in `confusion_matrix()`.

Please find below replicated and fixed code snippets:

```
Y_pred = model.predict(X_val)
Y_pred_classes = np.argmax(Y_pred,axis = 1) 

#Y_true = np.argmax(y_val,axis = 0) 

confusion_mtx = confusion_matrix(Y_true, Y_pred_classes) 
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
sns.heatmap(confusion_mtx, annot=True, linewidths=0.01,cmap="Greens",linecolor="gray", fmt= '.1f',ax=ax)
plt.xlabel("Predicted Label")
plt.ylabel("True Label")
plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
plt.show()
```